# Windows 7 suddenly unresponsive can't kill process

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome

We have 4 Windows 7 machines, but we've suddenly started having a problem with our Toshiba laptop.  Chrome/Firefox browsers suddenly stop responding but we are unable to kill the processes.  Even killing the whole process tree doesn't work.  And when this happens, I try to restart but the machine hangs at the "Shutting Down" screen.  The only thing I can do is force a hard shutdown using the power button.

The computer works for some period of time again before then exhibiting the same problem.  I can't isolate anything in particular that triggers the problem.  Browsers just stop working suddenly.

I'd like some ideas on the underlying problem.  The only things we really run on this machine are the browsers and maybe Word, Excel and Finaldraft.

Comment: Is there any disk activity?  Have you ever waited a long time (at least 15 minutes) to see if it comes back?  And this may sound odd, but, when this happens, go into Control Panel -> Admin Tools -> Services and restart Print Spooler.  (For some reason browsers hang up if the spooler is hung.)

Comment: I have found this sort of inability to do anything behavior is often connected to a bad hdd.   Its only a matter of time before BSOD happen if that is indeed the case.